# MENOR VALOR DE CADA LINHA DA MATRIZ

Tags: c, matriz

Preciso encontrar o menor valor de cada linha da matriz. Os valores aparecem faltando ou a mais (muito a mais).
[image: Enunciado da questão]

O que tenho até o momento:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main()
{

    float notas[][3] = {0};

    float menor = 0.0;
    
    //preenchendo matriz
    for(int aluno = 0; aluno < 10; aluno++)
    {
        for(int prova = 0; prova < 3; prova++)
        {
            notas[aluno][prova] = rand() % 10;    
        }
    }
    
    //Exibindo as notas
    printf("\t  COL 0      COL 1      COL 2\n");
    for(int aluno = 0; aluno < 10; aluno++)
    {
        printf("LINHA %d  - ", aluno);
        for(int prova = 0; prova < 3; prova++)
        {
            printf("%.2f      ", notas[aluno][prova]);   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 
    int Pior = 0;
    int Vpior[3] = {0};
 
    for(int aluno = 0; aluno < 10; aluno++)
    {
        Pior = 0;
        menor = notas[0][0];
        for(int prova = 0; prova < 3; prova++)
        {
            if(notas[aluno][prova]<menor)//
            {
                menor = notas[aluno][prova];
                Pior++;
            } 
        }
        Vpior[aluno] = Pior;
   }

    printf("\n");

    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        printf("Piores na:\nProva %d = %d\n", 
        r+1, Vpior[r]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sua declaração de notas está errada, use: `float notas[10][3] = {0};`. Note que por utilizar `notas[aluno][prova] = rand() % 10;` ninguém poderá tirar um 10, as notas irão variar entre 0 e 9. Aqui: `menor = notas[0][0];` deveria ser `menor = notas[aluno][0];`. Primeiro você tem que determinar a pior nota e depois varrer todos os alunos para contar os que tiraram esta nota (você está contando quantas vezes trocou a pior nota). Cuidado para contabilizar a pior nota de um aluno apenas uma vez.

Comment: Fiz a modificação que você falou, mas o resultado foi o mesmo de antes, ainda assim, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o comentário ficaria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main() {
    float notas[10][3] = {0};
    //preenchendo matriz
    for(int aluno = 0; aluno < 10; aluno++) {
        for(int prova = 0; prova < 3; prova++) {
            notas[aluno][prova] = (float) (rand() % 101) / 10;
        }
    }
    //Exibindo as notas
    printf("\t  COL 0  COL 1  COL 2\n");
    for(int aluno = 0; aluno < 10; aluno++) {
        printf("LINHA %d  - ", aluno);
        for(int prova = 0; prova < 3; prova++) {
            printf("%.2f  ", notas[aluno][prova]);   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
     
    int Vpior[3] = {0, 0, 0};
     
    for(int aluno = 0; aluno < 10; aluno++) {
        int menor = 0;
        for(int prova = 0; prova < 3; prova++) {
            if(notas[aluno][prova] < notas[aluno][menor]) {
                menor = prova;
            }  
        }
        Vpior[menor]++;
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        printf("Piores na:\nProva %d = %d\n", r+1, Vpior[r]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando em https://ideone.com/GErQab

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Eu gostaria de entender melhor, porque  colocar menor no lugar de prova, no IF?

Comment: No lugar de guardar a menor nota guarda-se o índice da menor nota (será considerada sempre a primeira encontrada, mesmo que existam notas iguais), dessa forma fica mais fácil acumular por prova (Vpior).

Comment: Thank you very much